# When importing Spinmob ValueError: time data '28 Aug 2020 21:03:06' does not match format '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python

I have been trying to troubleshoot for multiple hours but can't find anything.

I need to use the libraries [spinmob](https://github.com/Spinmob/spinmob) and a custom library made by my university (that uses spinmob) to analyze at some data.

When I use the standard python library `time` with the function `strptime("28 Aug 2020 21:03:06","%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")`. There is no problem at all. However, when I import spinmob, suddenly the function doesn't work anymore. If I reset the kernel and run `strptime` again, it works again...

Ultimately, the reason why I need this to work, is because my unversitie's custom library is using this `strptime` function, therefore, I'm trying to figure out why it stops working when loading the other library (spinmob).

When I load spinmob, I get this warning `Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.` I do not know if this has an impact on my problem, however.

What's also strange is that I know other people, who are able to load these things without any problem, hence, I'm assuming it must be something problematic on my system, but I'm running out of ideas to fix this problem. I've been running this in a virtual environment.

Not sure it'll be useful as info, but I'm using a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016), Monterey 12.1.

Any help is appreciated.

The minimum amount of code that produces this in my case is this:

```py
import spinmob
import time

time.strptime("28 Aug 2020 21:03:06","%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

yielding

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/christiandenis/opt/miniconda3/envs/testenv2/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 562, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/Users/christiandenis/opt/miniconda3/envs/testenv2/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '28 Aug 2020 21:03:06' does not match format '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
```

but if I do this:

```py
import time

time.strptime("28 Aug 2020 21:03:06","%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I get the expected result:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=28, tm_hour=21, tm_min=3, tm_sec=6, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=241, tm_isdst=-1)
```

I don't know what's going on...

Comment: Can you post the minimum amount of code that reproduces your error ?

Comment: @ApplePie I updated the question with it, thanks